# JSON and recursion

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

Sorry, I'm a newbie and it's been awhile since I've touched recursion, so I apologize if this question may seem a little basic. Basically I have a JSON structure like this:

```
  {
   "id": "1111",
   "name": "Outdoor Skiing",
   "parent_id": "1110",
   "parents": [
     {
        "id": "1000000",
        "name": "Movies"
     },
     {
        "id": "1000001",
        "name": "Outdoor Movies"
     }
   ]
 }
```

and basically I want to flip it in this structure:

```
{
  "id":"1000000",
  "name":"Movies",
  "children":[
     {
       "id":"1000001",
       "name":"Outdoor Movies",
       "children":[
          {
            "id":"1111",
            "name":"Outdoor Skiing",
            "parent_id":"1110",
            "parents: [....these can stay here....]
          }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me out on how to solve this using recursion? Thanks.

Comment: Initially, 1000000 & 1000001 are children of 1111; in the flipped version, 1000000 is the parent of 1000001 which is the parent of 1111.  I think you'll need to explain just what you mean by "flipped".

Comment: you're moving stuff around with no obvious pattern to replicate

Comment: The current data structure has the lowest-level category where the parents array holds the categories to which the lowest-level category falls under, in increasing order.

Comment: I thought a 2d array would be sufficient, but it appears not.

Comment: @user1717344: Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with using underscore, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var flip = function(theObject, newObject, offset) {
    offset ? offset++ : offset = 1;
    var newObj = _.first(_.last(theObject.parents, offset));
    newObject ? newObj.children = newObject : newObj.children = theObject;
    if (offset < _.size(theObject.parents))
    {
        flip(theObject, newObj, offset);
        return;
    }
    // at this point the 'newObj' variable contains the desired object
};
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3a3qf5/)

Edit: Due to popular demand :) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3a3qf5/1/)'s an example without underscore.

Comment: I wonder what you need underscore for. Isn't `_.first(_.last(theObject.parents, offset)) === theObject.parents[offset]` and `_.size(theObject.parents) === theObject.parents.length`?

Comment: Of course! (that is, if you do `theObject.parents[theObject.parents.length - offset]`)  And thank you for adding that.  You never NEED underscore.  I'm just too lazy when I'm whipping up code on the fly to go without it.

Comment: Hm, it just seemed a lot shorter with underscore (which is unusual)